# Oracle order by year, month

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a query which I want to order by year and then month. I have tryed order by to_date( depdate, 'mm' ) and TO_CHAR(depdate, 'YYYY/MM'). Here is an sqlfiddle to the table i am querying and the query itself [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cda08/2)

Comment: Why is the fiddle empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this query. If it is a date field, just plain order by would work for you. You need not use TO_CHAR to convert to string and then sort:

```
WITH TAB AS
(
 SELECT SYSDATE  DATEVAL FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT SYSDATE + 100 DATEVAL FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT SYSDATE -500 DATEVAL FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT SYSDATE + 30 DATEVAL FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT SYSDATE -30 DATEVAL FROM DUAL
) SELECT * FROM TAB
ORDER BY DATEVAL DESC
```

Comment: SELECT to_char(DEPDATE,'Mon-yyyy') AS MONTH, 
SUM(AMOUNTROOM) AS ROOMTOTAL, SUM(AMOUNTEXTRAS) AS EXTRATOTAL, 
SUM(AMOUNTEXTRAS + AMOUNTROOM) AS OATOTAL  
FROM checkins 
WHERE checkinstatus = 'D' AND depdate > TO_DATE('2013-12-01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND depdate <= TO_DATE('2014-04-10', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
GROUP BY to_char(DEPDATE,'Mon-yyyy')
order by to_date(to_char(DEPDATE,'Mon-yyyy'),'Mon-yyyy')

Answer (score 4):

You want to sort by the `date` value, not by the character string representation.  That means that you also want to `group by` the `date` value.  `trunc(<<date column>>, 'mm')` truncates a `date` to midnight on the first of the month.  So something like this

```
SELECT to_char(trunc(DEPDATE,'MM'), 'Mon-YYYY') AS MONTH, 
       SUM(AMOUNTROOM) AS ROOMTOTAL, 
       SUM(AMOUNTEXTRAS) AS EXTRATOTAL, 
       SUM(AMOUNTEXTRAS + AMOUNTROOM) AS OATOTAL 
FROM checkins 
WHERE checkinstatus = 'D' AND depdate > TO_DATE('2013-12-01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
  AND depdate <= TO_DATE('2014-04-10', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
GROUP BY trunc(depdate,'mm')
ORDER BY trunc(depdate,'mm');
```

should be what you're looking for.  See [the updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cda08/10)